# ListView become black in color whenuser scrolls

Tags: android

I have a ListView on my Android Activity. When I scroll it, the background of each text will be black until I click on one of the items. How I can fix it?

My [XML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML) file is

```
<ListView android:id="@id/list" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the [XML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML) file, which contains the listview, set the cache color hint to `#00000000`.

For example,

```
ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listVIew); 
lv.setCacheHintColor("#00000000")
```